# Select attribute value from XDocument where another attribute equals specific string value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following xml "example"

```
<methods>
  <method name="listcust" >
    <objects>
      <object name="ExampleTest" type="" version="">
        <properties>
          <property name="FirstName" type="text">
            <mappings>
              <mapping type="property">
                <property name="fn" />
              </mapping>
            </mappings>
          </property>
          <property name="LastName" type="text">
            <mappings>
              <mapping type="property">
                <property name="ln" />
              </mapping>
            </mappings>
          </property>
          <property name="BirthDate" type="datetime">
            <mappings>
              <mapping type="property">
                <property name="bd" />
              </mapping>
            </mappings>
          </property>
        </properties>
      </object>
    </objects>
  </method>
</methods>
```

and Im trying to select the "name" atribute value of say

```
<property name="LastName"  type="text">
```

when the "name" of the attribute within that element
 is equal to "ln" `<property name="ln" />`

I tried the following

```
var query = from p in xdoc.Descendants("property")
            where p.Descendants("property").Attributes("name").Contains(new XAttribute("name", "ln"))
            select p.Attribute("name").Value;

var res = query.ToList<string>();
```

but I get zero results back.

If I break it down step by step

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var props = xdoc.Descendants("property").Descendants("property");
var nameAtt = props.Attributes("name");
var contains = nameAtt.Contains(new XAttribute("name", "ln"));
```

Then I can see that **nameAtt** contains a list of the attributes including the `<property name="ln" />` one but the **contains** bool is still false

If anyone can please point out the correct way of doing the select\where or perharps even a completely different more efficient way of retrieving the one attribute value where its child node attribute value equals the one passed in

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change the `Where` condition:

```
where p.Descendants("property").Any(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "In")
```

`Any` will check if there is any element that has `name` attribute equals to `In`